# Me and X or X and me?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

When should I say, for instance, "Mary and me," and when should I say "Me and Mary?"

Example:

Which option should I use in the following sentence?

> After drinking our tea and saying goodbye to Hank, [...] made out way back
>   to the hotel.

Comment: How about "we"? Otherwise, "Mary and I."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is not a matter of grammar but of convention. It is generally thought to be more polite to mention the other person first.